# Validar datos numericos y letras en c# por consola (ayudaa)

Tags: c#, consola

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int datos;
    String op;
    String op2;

    do { 
        Console.WriteLine("Bienvenidos");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Tipo de triangulos");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Generar numeros pares");
        Console.WriteLine("Elija el numero de la opcion deseada");
            op = Console.ReadLine();


        switch (op)
        {
            case "1":
                Triangulo.TipoTriangulos();
                break;

            case "2":
                NumerosPares.GeneradorPares();
                break;


        }
         Console.WriteLine("Desea regresar al menu principal S/N");

        op2 = Console.ReadLine();

    } while (op2.ToUpper().Equals("S")) ;

        Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Veo que eres nuevo, así que te invito a que te des una vuelta por el [tour] del sitio y a que leas muy específicamente la sección [ask]. [Te he votado negativo porque solo dices que no funciona](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/31110) pero no explicas qué hay de malo. Por favor, da clic a [edit] para agregar detalles del problema.

Comment: :/ dije que quiero validar los datos que se ingresa, mas no he dicho que no sirve el codigo :/

Comment: De nueva cuenta, da clic a [edit] para añadir detalles de qué no funciona, cuál es el comportamiento esperado, por qué lo que tienes no resulta en dicho comportamiento y qué has intentado o investigado al respecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar estas validaciones podría utilizar alguna de estas opciones:

**1. Expresiones regulares**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
//Valida dígito
bool esValido = false;
Regex regexDigitos = new Regex(@"^\d$");
esValido = regexDigitos.IsMatch("9");
```

**2. Utilizando LINQ**

```
using System.Linq;
string cadenaEvaluar = "prueba";
bool esLetra = cadenaEvaluar.All(char.IsLetter);
bool esNumero = cadenaEvaluar.All(char.IsNumber);
```

Comment: muchas graciassss ]:) me sirvio muchisimooo

Comment: @AndresCarlos si la respuesta te sirvió, márcala como la respuesta correcta (la paloma que hay del lado izquierdo debajo del número) para que todos sepamos que se resolvió la duda y recompensar al compañero que lo resolvió.